# Violo Bridge Adjustments

Tags: violin, setup, bow, bridge

Is there any standard width height or breadth for violin bridges. I think I over sanded my bridge but it was pretty cheap it came with a 200 dollar violin. Can I sand the bridge myself carefully? Can anyone recommend any bridges? Also something to keep my violin clean? Also is there any solution for the rosin sticking on to the bow and the hair? Is it possible to get genuine horsehair? I live in India so online options would be good as there are not many sores around here. Any other general tips would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Standard dimensions of violin bridges: the strings should be about 12 mm apart at the bridge, and the height of the bridge should be such that the G string is about 5.5 mm above the end of the fingerboard, the E string about 3.5 mm, the others in between, such that the curve makes it possible to bow all strings separately easily.  This is subject to variation, depending on the violin and musical taste.

Keep your violin clean with a clean cloth.  You shouldn't need any cleaning fluid if you do it every time after playing.  Anything that will dissolve rosin might also remove varnish.  If necessary (on your own responsibility) you can use a cloth with water and a bit of alcohol.  Use care.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess that means I will have to shave down all of mine. Al the bridges are like an arc of a circle.

Comment: @Tarun - Well, the bridge should be like the arc of a circle: but a small part of the arc.  The fingerboard needs to have the right curve too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also is there any method to sand down the bridge properly because I am not able to sand the bottom legs of the bridge to match it to the curve of the violin. It ends up flat always. Also there is some discoloration on the fingerboard no changes in shape since I bought it. It is a second hand violin very old I guess it says 1716 on the inside. Is this a problem? Or just because the wood is old and also because of the secretions from the skin?

Comment: I will try and upload a picture.

Comment: @Tarun- about fitting the feet of the bridge to the violin: there's no easy way to do it, and it's almost impossible with sandpaper.  Ideally, you should do it with a knive or a chisel, until the feet fit perfectly.

Comment: Thanks once again. I will try to obtain one. My violin is clean now. The bow I removed the frog from its slot and try to scrape the rosin off. It did not go off at first. The sand paper shaved the wood too. Finally I got a brainwave and wiped it with some BD Alcohol swabs(the kind they used for injections. It came off so easily and now my bow looks like new minus a few scratches which look cool and the grip which I removed. It weighs much better in my hand now. After I adjusted the bridge it sounds almost as good as my 600 dollar violin. It resonates the sound. Sort of like a Reverb.

Comment: Any solutions for the discoloration?

Comment: Which discoloration?

Comment: Discoloration of the fingerboard I referred to in my previous comment.

Comment: If the fingerboard is discolored, it's probably dyed.  You can retouch it with a permanent ink marker.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I have not changed my strings since I got my violin(second hand) two years ago. I changed the original E string last week only as it snapped. There are no corrosions o the string they are I great shape and are probably used 2 hours a week. Should I change them or not? Also I want to change my bow hair, can I get the Mongolian Horsehair they sell on Amazon or should I buy it in person?

Comment: Unless your strings are very poor quality, you probably don't need to change them yet.  You should be able to tell from the sound: if they start sounding dull, it's time to change them.  Your question about horsehair is a big question that I can't really answer, because I don't know what Amazon's hair looks like, or the hair you could get in person, and I don't how your bow will be rehaired: will you have someone experienced do it, or try it yourself?  It's not at all easy to do well.

Comment: Thanks again. My master is pretty experienced and it looks pretty easy on How It's Made.

Comment: No problem, if your master is good.  But as I say, it's not all that easy. On the average,  I would say that a beginner would need to hair about thirty bows before getting halfway good at it.